# ID field being removed due to array push

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mongodb

I have a newGroups array which is an array of group objects. This array contains an id field alongside the actual mongoDB objectID. Projects contain a field called "assignedGroups" which is basically an array of group objects as well. My function should take all the new groups the user has selected and append that to the existing "assignedGroups" array for the selected project. id is a required field for a group. However, when I try to append the newGroups array to the "assignedGroups" array, the ID field somehow gets lost and I have no idea why this happens.

```
//add a group to a project given the client id and project id
router.post("/add_group", jwtVerify(['Admin', 'Manager']), expressAsyncHandler(
    async (req, res) => {
        console.log('req body: ', req.body);
        const clientId = req.body.clientId;
        const projectId = req.body.projectId;
        const newGroups: group = req.body.newGroups;

        try{
            console.log("received client id: ", clientId);
            const client = await ClientModel.findOne({ id: clientId });


            if(client) {
                const project = client.projects.find((project) => {
                    return project.id == projectId;
                });

                if(project) {
                    console.log("group is: ", newGroups);
                    project.assignedGroups?.push(...newGroups);
                    console.log('new project: ', project);
                    await client.save();

                    res.status(201).send(project);
                } else {
                    res.status(404).send("Project not found");
                }
    
            } else {
                res.status(404).send("Client not found")
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error is: ', error);
            res.status(500).send("Internal server error adding group to clients project");
        }
    } 
));
```

I receive the following error in addition to this:
`` error is:  Error: client validation failed: projects.0.assignedGroups.2.id: Path `id` is required. ``

I have tried printing console logs everywhere and have determined the line responsible for causing the error. It happens specifically when I try to push the newGroups onto the assignedGroups but I have no idea why the data changes. This is the result of my console log for the following lines of code:

```
   console.log("group is: ", newGroups);
   project.assignedGroups?.push(...newGroups);
   console.log('new project: ', project);

   //OUTPUT
group is:  [
  {
    _id: '6515880ccbb4d907d4aee87b',
    id: '1',
    groupName: 'Frontend',
    backgroundPhoto: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ds2qotysb/image/upload/v1688755927/ayajgq9sgud81qzc.jpg',
    people: [
      '64b15aa72b77e4a923cafdc8',
      '64b159e72b77e4a923cafda6',
      '64b3c70fb49306cf1b0b6ff2',
      '64b42de378a9f73779d70d66',
      '64b432fd2512db8f87d31e75',
      '64b43ea14a3e267132a5f292',
      '6515867b44e85bf4fb3a6ddd',
      '65159861578f8e1bf619aea1',
      '65159c216ae2377b2ef80ff4',
      '6515a4986ae2377b2ef8101e',
      '64b159c52b77e4a923cafd9e',
      '65161f64c8530d9744568efd',
      '6536ebca578f8e1bf619d65d'
    ],
    tickets: [
      '1',  '2',  '3',  '4',  '5',  '6',  '7',
      '8',  '9',  '10', '11', '12', '13', '15',
      '16', '17', '18', '20', '21', '22', '23',
      '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30',
      '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37',
      '47', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58',
      '59', '60', '62', '65', '67', '68', '71'
    ],
    __v: 1
  }
]

new project:  {
  id: '8',
  name: 'Org',
  logo: '../../assets/project-logos/notebook.png',
  color: 'pink-cl',
  assignedGroups: [
    {
      id: '2',
      groupName: 'Integration',
      backgroundPhoto: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ds2qotysb/image/upload/v1695910934/ayajgq9sgud81qzc.jpg',
      people: [Array],
      tickets: [Array],
      _id: new ObjectId("65158c173c0c30898fb9aa32"),
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      groupName: 'Security',
      backgroundPhoto: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ds2qotysb/image/upload/v1695911006/ayajgq9sgud81qzc.jpg',
      people: [Array],
      tickets: [],
      _id: new ObjectId("65158c5f3c0c30898fb9aa4f"),
      __v: 0,
      id: '4'
    },
    {
      groupName: 'Frontend',
      backgroundPhoto: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ds2qotysb/image/upload/v1688755927/ayajgq9sgud81qzc.jpg',
      people: [Array],
      tickets: [Array],
      _id: new ObjectId("6515880ccbb4d907d4aee87b"),
      __v: 1
    }
  ],
  _id: new ObjectId("6515a50078d33c3995f980b9"),
  highPriorityTime: '1h',
  lowPriorityTime: '1w',
  mediumPriorityTime: '1d'
}
```

As you can see, the Frontend project which is the one that was supposed to be appended indeed does not contain the ID field however, when printing the newGroup, it's there. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

//EDIT
I have now also tried a slightly different approach with seemingly no progress:

```
if(client) {
                const project = client.projects.find((project) => {
                    return project.id == projectId;
                });

                if(project) {
                    console.log("groups are: ", newGroups);
                    for (const newGroup of newGroups) {
                        const newGroupWithId = { ...newGroup, id: newGroup.id };
                        console.log("newGroupWithId is: ", newGroupWithId);
                        project.assignedGroups?.push(newGroupWithId);

                        if (project.assignedGroups && project.assignedGroups.length > 0) {
                            const lastGroup = project.assignedGroups[project.assignedGroups.length - 1];
                            console.log('last group: ', lastGroup);
                            if (!lastGroup.id) {
                                lastGroup.id = newGroupWithId.id;
                                console.log('last group in assignedGroups after id update: ', lastGroup);
                            }
                        }
                      }
                    console.log('new project: ', project);
                    await client.save();

                    res.status(201).send(project);
                } else {
                    res.status(404).send("Project not found");
                }
    
            }
```

Over here, I try a very manual way to first make sure the id does exist for the group when I'm pushing it to the assignedGroups. I even check if the last group in assignedGroups does not contain the id, then I add the id. The code enters the final if block:
`if (!lastGroup.id)` but still does not update the last group in the assignedGroups array with the id I want! Here is the output:

```
newGroupWithId:  {
  _id: '6515880ccbb4d907d4aee87b',
  id: '1',
  groupName: 'Frontend',
  backgroundPhoto: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ds2qotysb/image/upload/v1688755927/ayajgqes9sguidd81qzc.jpg',
  people: [
    '64b15aa72b77e4a923cafdc8',
    '64b159e72b77e4a923cafda6',
    '64b3c70fb49306cf1b0b6ff2',
    '64b42de378a9f73779d70d66',
    '64b432fd2512db8f87d31e75',
    '64b43ea14a3e267132a5f292',
    '6515867b44e85bf4fb3a6ddd',
    '65159861578f8e1bf619aea1',
    '65159c216ae2377b2ef80ff4',
    '6515a4986ae2377b2ef8101e',
    '64b159c52b77e4a923cafd9e',
    '65161f64c8530d9744568efd',
    '6536ebca578f8e1bf619d65d'
  ],
  tickets: [
    '1',  '2',  '3',  '4',  '5',  '6',  '7',
    '8',  '9',  '10', '11', '12', '13', '15',
    '16', '17', '18', '20', '21', '22', '23',
    '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30',
    '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37',
    '47', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58',
    '59', '60', '62', '65', '67', '68', '71'
  ],
  __v: 1
}
last group:  {
  groupName: 'Frontend',
  backgroundPhoto: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ds2qotysb/image/upload/v1688755927/ayajgqes9sguidd81qzc.jpg',
  people: [
    new ObjectId("64b15aa72b77e4a923cafdc8"),
    new ObjectId("64b159e72b77e4a923cafda6"),
    new ObjectId("64b3c70fb49306cf1b0b6ff2"),
    new ObjectId("64b42de378a9f73779d70d66"),
    new ObjectId("64b432fd2512db8f87d31e75"),
    new ObjectId("64b43ea14a3e267132a5f292"),
    new ObjectId("6515867b44e85bf4fb3a6ddd"),
    new ObjectId("65159861578f8e1bf619aea1"),
    new ObjectId("65159c216ae2377b2ef80ff4"),
    new ObjectId("6515a4986ae2377b2ef8101e"),
    new ObjectId("64b159c52b77e4a923cafd9e"),
    new ObjectId("65161f64c8530d9744568efd"),
    new ObjectId("6536ebca578f8e1bf619d65d")
  ],
  tickets: [
    '1',  '2',  '3',  '4',  '5',  '6',  '7',
    '8',  '9',  '10', '11', '12', '13', '15',
    '16', '17', '18', '20', '21', '22', '23',
    '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30',
    '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37',
    '47', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58',
    '59', '60', '62', '65', '67', '68', '71'
  ],
  _id: new ObjectId("6515880ccbb4d907d4aee87b"),
  __v: 1
}
last group in assignedGroups after id update:  {
  groupName: 'Frontend',
  backgroundPhoto: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ds2qotysb/image/upload/v1688755927/ayajgqes9sguidd81qzc.jpg',
  people: [
    new ObjectId("64b15aa72b77e4a923cafdc8"),
    new ObjectId("64b159e72b77e4a923cafda6"),
    new ObjectId("64b3c70fb49306cf1b0b6ff2"),
    new ObjectId("64b42de378a9f73779d70d66"),
    new ObjectId("64b432fd2512db8f87d31e75"),
    new ObjectId("64b43ea14a3e267132a5f292"),
    new ObjectId("6515867b44e85bf4fb3a6ddd"),
    new ObjectId("65159861578f8e1bf619aea1"),
    new ObjectId("65159c216ae2377b2ef80ff4"),
    new ObjectId("6515a4986ae2377b2ef8101e"),
    new ObjectId("64b159c52b77e4a923cafd9e"),
    new ObjectId("65161f64c8530d9744568efd"),
    new ObjectId("6536ebca578f8e1bf619d65d")
  ],
  tickets: [
    '1',  '2',  '3',  '4',  '5',  '6',  '7',
    '8',  '9',  '10', '11', '12', '13', '15',
    '16', '17', '18', '20', '21', '22', '23',
    '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30',
    '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37',
    '47', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58',
    '59', '60', '62', '65', '67', '68', '71'
  ],
  _id: new ObjectId("6515880ccbb4d907d4aee87b"),
  __v: 1
}
```

Comment: How were the two other `assignedGroups` (id 2 and 4) added to the array?

Comment: Well the funny thing is, the exact same code works on the localhost of the other developers. It does not work on my localhost. I was also responsible for deploying the app and it does not work on the deployed app either. Id 2 was added via localhost on the other developers machine whereas security was added by a different developer that bypassed the schema rules to validate that id was indeed missing in the DB. We later added the id 4 to the DB manually. We used tools such as diff checker to compare code to ensure it's all the same. Even checked the .env files because we were so skeptical.

Comment: @Geshode I know it seems impossible to you but I am so stumped myself. I usually never ask for help on stack overflow but I honestly don't know how to deal with this problem. We are all on the exact same branch, with the exact same code. I've tried recloning the repo and not even that helped.

Comment: We are using a microservices architecture. This code is for the client service. I thought that if the code works on their local machines, then perhaps they should deploy their client service and then we can just route our API calls to their deployed service instead. They made a copy of the client directory (client service) and deployed it to Railway. Funny enough, their code that worked on their local machines would now have the same error when the client service is on Railway. So only my machine, and Railway identify the error. If the server is set up on their machines, there is no error.